# What SQL is being processed in a given transaction, which appears in DBA_2PC_PENDING?

Tags: oracle, transactions, distributed-transactions

To be more precise, let's consider a situation when there're some in-doubt transactions which appeared in DBA_2PC_PENDING view.

I have the local and global numbers of these transactions, but wanted to know if we are able to get information about what SQL is being processed inside them, or what was done. I googled  on the topic, but didn't find anything really useful.

I tried to find any information about them in `v$transaction`, but faced failure.
This query returns nothing for columns from `v$transaction`:

```
SELECT * FROM dba_2pc_pending p, v$transaction t 
WHERE 
    substr(p.local_tran_id, 1, instr(p.local_tran_id, '.', 1, 1) - 1) = t.xidusn(+) 
    and substr(p.local_tran_id, instr(p.local_tran_id, '.', 1, 1) + 1, instr(p.local_tran_id, '.', 1, 2) - instr(p.local_tran_id, '.', 1, 1) - 1) = t.xidslot(+) 
    and substr(p.local_tran_id, instr(p.local_tran_id, '.', 1, 2) + 1) = t.xidsqn(+);
```

Parsing of the local transaction id is correct, I checked it three times.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why v$transaction shows nothing may be that the distributed transaction has already been commited (or rolled back) on node being queried - check STATE column.

You may ask DBA_2PC_NEIGHBORS to check connections for incoming/outgoing transactions:

```
SELECT * FROM dba_2pc_neighbors WHERE local_tran_id = 'x.x.x';
```

On one of the participating nodes you will eventually find pending transaction.

Check Oracle docs on how to navigate the participating sites to find out who is the coordinator and which of the nodes failed: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_txnman007.htm

Comment: The problem is that they appear and dissapear quickly, and it's kinda impossible to be that fast that you're able to catch it on the other node. But the fact they appear is not good, because they still cause problems.

Comment: What kind of problems they cause? They should appear in the table as long as they are pending, just as the name suggests. If they disappear, means they are resolved (should be at least). If you want to "catch" the SQL issued, maybe you just should check [auditing](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/auditing-10gr2.php)?